# Checking the feasibility of a system of inequalities

Tags: constrained-optimization, linear-programming

I have $m$ inequalities involving $n$ variables as follows
$$a_{1,j} x_1 +a_{2,j} x_2 +\dots +a_{n,j} x_n>0 \quad \text{for} \quad 1 \leq j \leq m$$

How can I check if a solution exists (with the possible help of computer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check feasibility of a set of linear inequalities by constructing a linear programming (LP) problem with a "dummy" objective, e.g., 
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n} &\;0\\
\text {subject to } & \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j} x_i \geq0 \text{ for all } 1 \leq j \leq m.
\end{align}
$$

Any reasonable LP solver will either return an "optimal" $\{x_i\}$ (implying feasibility of the inequalities) or will return a proof of infeasibility (via Farkas' Lemma).

Comment: Dear Stelios, what does $\text{max} 0$ stand for?

Comment: @apt45 This is a dummy optimization problem. There is no real objective function we are intersted to maximize, so we set it to a fixed value (independent of $\{x_i\}$). It could be any other number, e.g., 15.324324, whatever. The solver will, of course try to solve the problem and will trivially return an optimal objective function equal lto $0$ (which we don't care about) but, at the same time, will make sure that the "optimal" $\{x_i\}$ satisfy the linear constraints, which is what we care about.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Stelios' answer, but it could use some fleshing out. This problem is called the "Phase One" problem.

First, convert your problem into "standard form".
\begin{align*}
\min_x 0 \\
s.t. \;\;Ax =b \\
x \ge 0
\end{align*}
This can always be done for problems of your type, though it may require introducing new variables. Next, solve the Phase One problem for the new problem.
You can solve it by solving the following LP:

\begin{align*}
\min \sum_i z_i \\
Ax + z = b \\
z \ge 0 \\
x \ge 0
\end{align*}

A feasible initial point of this new problem is $x=0$, $z=b$ (assuming $b\ge 0$. If not, just flip the right signs in $A$ to make it so).
Once you reach the minimum of this linear program, you will be at a corner of the polytope that you actually care about.
If the minimum is nonzero, then you know that no such point exists.

Answer (score 1):

In general, finding a feasible point -- more specifically a vertex of the feasible region -- is a non-trivial task. This is the first step of any implementation of the vertex algorithm to solve linear problems, and it is typically done by solving a *dual* problem. In this dual problem, we know that the origin is a feasible vertex and that the *solution* of the dual problem (which we can again find through the vertex algorithm) is a feasible vertex of the original problem.

In your case, this means that you can test for feasibility by writing down a "fake" linear problem (as suggested by @Stellos in his/her post), constructing the dual problem, and solving it. If it succeeds, then you have a feasible vertex of your original set of constraints; there is then no need to solve the fake problem, of course. Any commercial LP solver will also be able to do that for you, though it may nevertheless try to solve for the fake problem.

Comment: If a feasible point exists for the primal, then the dual solution is the zero vector. This is Farkas' Lemma, and is a consequence of weak Lagrangian duality. What you're referring to as the "dual" is actually the Phase-One problem described by Tyler Oslen.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.